# How to replace six or more authors in text with et al. (APA style) in model5-names.bst from elsarticle.cls?

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, apa6

APA style requires six or more authors to be abbreviated in text with "et al.".

For example:

(Murray, Wylie, Higgins, Javitt, Schroeder & Foxe, 2002)

shout be abbreviated to

(Murray et al., 2002)

Could someone help me out with specifying this in the model5-names.bst file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem with the following `\shortcites{key}\citep{key}`. It will give the short version of the particular reference. So, instead of modifying the style (.bst) file, this is useful to shorten the references with six or more authors in the tex code itself, 'per case'.